# Error in alpha * 255 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot the data from csv and received following error:
**Error in alpha * 255 : non-numeric argument to binary operator**

Here's my code written in R:

```
ggplot(subset(Z_score_summary,occ==1),aes(x = Titles.ordered,y = Z_score,ymin=Zmin,ymax=Zmax,group=date) ) +
  
  geom_ribbon(data=subset(Z_score_summary,occ==1), aes(x = Titles.ordered,ymin=Zmin,ymax=Zmax,fill="Historical Z-Scores"), color=0, alpha="0.5",show.legend=TRUE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey")) +                                         
  
  geom_hline(yintercept=3.1, linetype="dashed",size=1.2) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=2.0, linetype="solid",size=0.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1.0, linetype="solid",size=0.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.0, linetype="solid",size=0.5) +
  
  geom_line(data=Z_score_summary,aes(x = Titles.ordered, y = Z_score, group = date, color = date,linetype=date), size=1.5) +
  
  annotate(geom="text", label='Z-Score = 3.1 (FTY > 99.9%)', x=13.2, y=3.3, vjust=0, size = 4.5)+
  annotate(geom="text", label='FTY = 97.7%', x=13.2, y=2.1, vjust=0, size = 3.5)+
  annotate(geom="text", label='FTY = 84.1%', x=13.2, y=1.1, vjust=0, size = 3.5)+
  annotate(geom="text", label='FTY = 50.0%', x=13.2, y=0.1, vjust=0, size = 3.5)+
  
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#00FF00", "#0033CC","#FF3300","#FF3300"),guide = guide_legend(override.aes=aes(fill=NA)))+
  
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1,1,1,0)) +
  ylab("Z-Scores (none)") +
  labs(title=paste("Process Capability\n")) +
  scale_y_continuous(minor_breaks = seq(0, 15, by = 1),
                     breaks = seq(0, 15, by = 5),
                     #limits = c(0,25),
                     expand = c(0, 0))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,15)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x  = element_text(size=10, angle = 45, hjust = 1, face="bold", color = 'black'),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=14, color = 'black'),
        axis.text.y  = element_text(size=10, face="bold", color = 'black'),
        axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'black', size = 1, linetype = 'solid'),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(0.3, "cm"),
        axis.line.x = element_line(size=1.2),
        axis.line.y = element_line(size=1.2),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12, face="bold", color = 'black'),
        legend.justification=c(0,1), legend.position=c(0,1),
        legend.background = element_rect(colour = "black"),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.85, "cm"),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = rel(2), face="bold"))

ggsave(width = 16, height = 9, dpi = 200,"Plot_summary.png", plot = last_plot())
```

Does anyone can help me with that issue? What's a bit strage that it used to work few months ago and suddenly stopped working while I move to new PC (and new version or R).

Thanks!

Comment: In your `geom_ribbon(`, has `color=0` always been 0?

Comment: Yes. I have never changed it.

Comment: Change `alpha="0.5"` to `alpha = 0.5`. The `alpha` value should be numeric, not a string. It's possible version updates made this more strict.

Comment: And perhaps 'color' to 'colour' as ?geom_ribbon says this is the recognized aesthetic.

Comment: @Chris either color spelling works. (In the earliest versions of ggplot, only `colour` worked, at least for some things.)